# Greendao insert into new table issue

Tags: android, greendao

I'm working on an android app already built by other. and this project has green dao as database framework. This project has already some tables built and working great. recently i've added two tables and tables have also been generated. but the problem is i can't insert into these newly generated tables. is there any thing i've missed like do we have to migrate the database or something if i added new tables? the table dao sessions are also coming null . can somebody give me some ideas about this?

Comment: Have you upgraded the schemaVersion in the app's build.gradle?

Comment: No I didn't. do we have to upgrade schemaVersion after generating any new tables?

Comment: Yes you have to upgrade the schema Version whenever you do any changes to the database such as adding a new table or deleting a table or maybe altering an existing table.

Comment: thanks for the help @HuzaifaIftikhar it works now